# How do I get the number of existing specific names in a JSON

Tags: javascript, json, for-loop

i need the same execution for each "book", but how do i loop through it?

My `JSON`:

```
{
  "bookstore": {
    "book": [
      {
        "-category": "cooking",
        "title": {
          "-lang": "en",
          "#text": "Everyday Italian"
        },
        "author": "Giada De Laurentiis",
        "year": "2005",
        "price": "30.00"
      },
      {
        "-category": "children",
        "title": {
          "-lang": "en",
          "#text": "Harry Potter"
        },
        "author": "J K. Rowling",
        "year": "2005",
        "price": "29.99"
      },
      {
        "-category": "web",
        "title": {
          "-lang": "en",
          "#text": "Learning XML"
        },
        "author": "Erik T. Ray",
        "year": "2003",
        "price": "39.95"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

my source code is to give out a heading for each book and the ones between contents, all this is no problem.
only with looping i have my problems.
Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Can you show us what you’ve done in your code so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What exactly are you trying to achieve?
If you want to loop through book you can do it like this

```
bookstore.book.forEach(elem=>{
 //logic
}
```

Otherwise if theres anything else please elaborate!

Comment: how do i handle it when there's another array in a json array? <br> can i use it like that: ``` bookstore.forEach(elem=> <br> bookstore.book.forEach(elem=>{ <br> }); <br> });```

Comment: If there is another array inside that element you can add an additional check 

```
bookstore.book.forEach(elem=>{
 if(elem.constructor===Array){
     elem.forEach(el=>{})}
else{
  //logic}

})

```

Answer (score 1):

You have to access the nested object and then the array inside it.

```
var bookstoreObj= yourJson["bookstore"];
var bookArr=bookstoreObj["book"];
```

now you have your book array, iterate on that.

```
for(var i=0;i<bookArr.length;i++)
{
   var book=bookArr[i];
  //get value which you want:-category, author,year, price like this
   var author= book["author"];

  //to access title object:
  var title=book["title"] ;
  //now you can access:-lang, #text field
  var lang= title["-lang"];
  var text=title["#text"];

}
```

here,

> yourJson

infers to your

> jsonObject

you have shown.